# Is there a way to be able to use the python shell to call functions while the tkinter window is running

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, console, autohotkey

I wrote a program to start and stop an AutoHotKey script in the tkinter GUI for my non-coding coworkers to use but the autohotkey script has to be able to send commands through the python shell and I just realized that while the tkinter window is open, I am unable to send commands through the shell. I know theres an AutoHotKey library for Python but I really don't want to have to rewrite too much if possible. Is there anyway to keep the tkinter window up and running while also calling other functions from the shell?

I don't know what to try other than rewriting the whole thing using the AHK library.

Comment: Probably you can do with threads. Create a thread and start subprocess session. Read outputs and send commands via subprocess library while running in thread. Your main thread would continue to handlw tkinter without a problem

Comment: Thanks! I just put the mainloop() as the target for the thread and it works! Thanks so much